# Как остановить выполнение AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery

В общем дело такое Как остановить выполнение AJAX, и вернуться к заполнению форы если ответ от сервера не устараивае.

Я ее могу проверить как на сервере так и на стороне клиента с помощью JS
Так вот: если положиться на то что там добросовестные пользователи и они не знают про F12  про // 
то все гут.

Но если нет, на стороне сервера а тоесть с помощью PHP можно и нужно завернуть назад к заполнению вормы.

Ответ оправильности формы можно получить только в sucess(function(data){data.uname})

data.uname массив в котором уже имя прошло проверку регуляркой, так вот если прошло то ок а если не прошло то нужно не отправлять форму а продолжать заполнять ее.

```
success:(function(data){
                        if(data.uname===1) {
                                $('#inputregName').css('border', '');
                                }
                                else{
                                    $('#inputregName').css('border', 'red 1px solid');
                                }})
```

Comment: Если пришел ответ от сервера - уже нечего останавливать

Comment: и что же делать?

Comment: Добавьте подробностей в вопрос. Сейчас непонятно в чем именно проблема. Например почему нынешний запрос мешает вернуться к заполнению формы?

Answer (score -1):

Вы уже выполнили запрос на сайт и получили ответ. Если вам необходимо, к примеру, не сохранять профиль если не указан E-Mail - это делается уже в самом скрипте, который обрабатывает данные, отправленные в форме. Как вариант - сделать сохранение функцией `$profile->save()`, но перед сохранением пробегаться по всем полям и если что-то не устраивает - `return false;` Вместо false вы можете вернуть и скрипт, например `<script>alert('Ошибка в форме...')</script>` который можете запихнуть в любое место сайта и этот код выполнится

Так что все валидации необходимо производить при обработке формы на сервере, а уже если нужно подсвечивать какое поле некорректно или выводить ошибку - то возвращаете какой-то специально сформированный ответ и уже его обрабатываете в success